# Put borders to a text mesh

Tags: components, unity-game-engine

I want to make a simple text box prefab. How can I keep the text in the textbox? *Very simple question :)*

[image: text box preview]

Comment: I'd recommend a content size fitter if you want to adjust the size of the box. Have a look at this link: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/HOWTO-UIFitContentSize.html

Comment: couldn't be easier - see answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couldn't be easier

(1) Add a canvas

***HINT*** always select "Scale with screen size" (Unity accidentally setthe wrong default there; you only ever use "Scale with screen size")

(3) Add UI -> Text

Set **horizontal to *WRAP***

Look at the large yellow arrow

Leave the vertical as overflow (just choose a small height, say 10, for the box: it is irrelevant).

Set the width of the box to whatever you want - other large yellow arrow.

[image]

(In your specific example, it looks like you have a gray box, with a Text sitting on top of that gray box. You should simply **make the text box expand to fit the gray box**.)

Unity's reactive layout system is fantastic. If you're just getting started with it, search on here for QA and don't hesitate to post more questions. It is hard to master, but worth it.

Comment: (sry for the late reply) yes exactly. It's exactly a box with a text mesh and two boxes as its children. I don't really know a better way to make text boxes. How do I combine the canvas with such a text box?

Comment: Thanks I get it now. I didn't have good knowledge about canvases and stuff so I spent some hours on youtube. The problem's that I've implemented many text boxes as simple cube game objects with 3d text meshes so it would take me time to convert the text to UI elements. I think I might have to do it eventually. Sorry I'm  not focusing well because of deadlines and people not doing what they should and things like that. Thanks again :)

Comment: Ah, it's tough but you'll absolutely have to change to the UI system.  Looking for your next question!